# Comparing multiple columns to a list with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, compare

I have this data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": [1942,  95870, 85228,  6636],
                   "0": [1524, 8788, 9899, 27172],
                   "1": [1333, 4476, 78783, 90832],
                   "2": [2021, 2022, 34522, 38479]})
df1.set_index(df1['user'])
print(df1)

    user      0      1      2
0   1942   1524   1333   2021
1  95870   8788   4476   2022
2  85228   9899  78783  34522
3   6636  27172  90832  38479
```

`df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows (real data has 1 million) and each row for `df2` consist of several numbers in **square brackets**, separated by a comma as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                   "0": [[1123, 2021, 8788]]})
```

The numbers in square brackets vary from 1 to 20, in this case it's only 3. However, the number rows for `df2` and `df1` are the same.

```
print(df2)
           0
0  [1123, 2021, 8788]
```

What I would like to do is to pick a user from `df1`, for example `user1942` and compare if any of the three numbers in that row `(1524, 1333, 2021)` are in any of the corresponding square brackets in df2 `[1123, 2021, 8788]`. A boolean of 1 if True or 0 otherwise, or any other representation will be helpful.

**Update: The comparison should be row by row. That is one row in `df1` versus it's corresponding row in `df2`.**

The output could look like this, or anything closer:
Output: Since 2021 is in df2, the answer is True. Then move to the next user in df1, compare that user's 3 numbers with the corresponding row numbers in df2, etc.

```
user      status
1942        1
...
```

I know that there are a number of questions about comparing multiple columns but I could not find something reproducible or similar to this context.

Comment: It's not clear, you want to do this one by one? or for all rows simultaneously. Also, you showed only 1 row for df2, what happens if you have many? Please update your question to clarify this ambiguity.

Comment: I have added the update to clarify your question. And to double confirm, the rows in `df2` are many, same size with `df1` so the comparison can be thought of 'pairwise' in a sense. Unfortunately I could not produce more rows for `df2` but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: @SquidGame Are there always unique numbers in `df1` and `df2` in each row?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma some numbers are unique but others are not, what I am doing is to compare if any of the numbers in `df` rows is in any of the numbers in `df2`. Certain numbers may repeat in `df2` since they were obtained through a prediction function. I hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the indices of df1 are the same of the ones of df2 and that the relation between the rows of the two is 1:1, I would do something like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
  for index, row in df1.iterrows():
  to_find = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
  to_check = df2.iloc[index][0]
  if [True for i in to_find if i in to_check]:
    df3 = df3.append([1])
  else:
    df3 = df3.append([0])
```

you create a list for the values in df1 and then ckeck if any of the values appear in the list in the corresponding df2 row, if at least one value matches you append 1 to the resulting df3, otherwise 0.
Always assuming your relation is 1:1, now in df3 you have the index corresponding to the user selected and the boolean value to verify the match.

## EDIT: Improved Daniele's solution to allow iteration on integers

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    to_find = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]]
    to_check = df2.iloc[index][0]
    to_numpy = np.array([to_check])
    to_list  = to_numpy.tolist()
    if [True for i in to_find if i in to_list]:
        df3 = df3.append([1])
    else:
        df3 = df3.append([0])
```

Comment: The solution is producing an error `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable` on this line: `if [True for i in to_find if i in to_check]:`.       I can confirm that `to_find` and `to_check` contain the correct `int` values. Where do you suggest I can modify?

Comment: This error occurs if you try to iterate over a single element, an int in this case, and honestly I didn't get this error when I tried it. Are you sure you integrate it correctly in your code?

Comment: Maybe in your df2 there are some rows which contains a single int value and not a list, producing that behaviour

Comment: Hi, I accepted your changes, does it work now? I think the example you provided wasn't with the right data type since for me worked the previous code, let me know!

Comment: Yes, it works. The real data has some rows with only one value which created the error, and now it works regardless of the number of values being compared to in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a very elegant solution without relying on for loops, but if we convert the dataframes to np.arrays (or even lists) first, we can get a very decent workaround.
First, we manipulate `df1` to obtain organized records

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": [1123,  95870, 85228,  6636],
                   "0": [1524, 8788, 9899, 27172],
                   "1": [1333, 4476, 78783, 90832],
                   "2": [2021, 2022, 34522, 38479]})
df1 = df1.set_index('user', drop=True)
print(df1)
```

```py
           0      1      2
user                      
1123    1524   1333   2021
95870   8788   4476   2022
85228   9899  78783  34522
6636   27172  90832  38479
```

Then, we do the same to `df2`. The proposed method works even if the two dataframes have a different number of columns.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1123, 2021, 8788, 6636],
                    [1333, 2023, 4477, 78783],
                    [1524, 2023, 9899, 27172],
                    [2021, 2023, 345233,38479]]
                    )

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_numpy().tolist())
df2 = df2.set_axis(df1.index, axis=0)
print(df2)
```

```py
          0     1       2      3
user                            
1123   1123  1333    8788   6636
95870  1333  2023    4477  78783
85228  1524  2023    9899  27172
6636   2021  2023  345233  38479
```

Finally, we produce the desired values using a list comprehension that iterates over rows to check whether they have elements in common.

```py
inter = [np.isin(arr[0], arr[1]).any() for arr in zip(df1.to_numpy(), df2.to_numpy())]
print(inter)
```

```py
[True, False, True, True]
```

Comment: This solution is not exactly what I have asked, I can elaborate if my question is not clear. `df2` does not have separate columns like in your case but it's a single column with values in `square brackets` such as `[1123, 2021, 8788]`. Besides, your solution seem to be checking each row in `df1` against a column in `df2`. I hope this helps to clarify the question, or I may be misunderstanding your solution @saiden

Comment: So `df2` is like this? `pd.DataFrame({"0": [[1123, 2021, 8788], [2021, 95870, 4476]]})`